# react-navigation - createBottomTabNavigator not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo

Hello I am making a react native app with expo. Following is my app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import WelcomeScreen from "./screens/WelcomeScreen";
import AuthScreen from "./screens/AuthScreen";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
       Welcome: WelcomeScreen,
       Auth: AuthScreen
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and following is my package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^28.0.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-28.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

The app is running without any errors but it does not display the bottom navigation tab! I have checked the syntax from the official documentation as well and i fear it may be due to version of react-navigation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my welcomescreen component file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from "react-native";

class WelcomeScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Hello this is working!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

auth component is also same except the change of name.

Comment: It is not displaying the components either... All i am getting is a blank page

Comment: Try to create your `MainNavigator` outside of the `render` method instead.

Comment: Does not work. same result

Comment: Try to put tab navigator without `<View/>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version is not the issue. The issue is with the custom `StyleSheet` and `<View/>` Component

You can [View the edited app here](https://snack.expo.io/r1clFZqQ7)

In case u want to try in uer app package.json is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "6.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "0.18.5",
    "react-navigation": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

and App.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

class AuthScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    AuthScreen Works!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Hello this is working!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
            Auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
            Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
        });

        // return (
        //     <View style={styles.container}>
        //       <MainNavigator/>
        //     </View>
        // );

        return <MainNavigator/>
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: does not work. class is used in the official docs too, so i dont think this is the case. version conflict might be there

Comment: Yeah issue was with the view tag. Apparently newer versions do not accept View tag anymore. Thanks I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Can you please upvote the question as well... it will help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a stack navigator as your first screen and then try to load Welcome screen and Other screen as Bottom Tab Navigator, I have used this structure in many of my apps try this https://github.com/davekedar/React-Navigation-V2-Authflow

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading to

```
"react-navigation": "^2.13.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this today with `"react-navigation": "^4.3.9"`.

Fixed by setting `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>` instead of just `<View>`. This problem does not occur if you wrap the navigator in something other than `<View>` (i.e. `<Fragment>`).

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8449

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#nothing-is-visible-on-the-screen-after-adding-a-view